# Map Service Update - clearing browser temp files

Tags: arcgis-server, mapserver, arcgis-flex-api, administration

I'm noticing whenever I make a change to an ArcGIS map service (add layer, remove layer...etc) I always have to clear server cache and my internet browser temp files in order for my flex viewer app to not give an error.  This can be problematic for any user viewing the application before and after an update has been made to the service.  What is the strategy to prevent these errors from occurring on users accessing an app that may need periodic updates?

Changing the application url (I'm guessing there must be something better than this)?

Answer (score 1):

I keep track of updates (versions). If there is a new update when a user makes a service request, I use the [REST api](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/SDK/REST/clearcache.html) to programmatically clear the cache.